# Составление Mysql запроса

Tags: php, mysql

Как можно перенести определенные(поле статус которых 1) записи из 2ой таблицы в первую и при этом вставить в 1 дополнительные значения, которых нет во 2ой таблице?
Пытался сделать так

```
$th_close = $GLOBALS['mysqli']->query("SELECT * FROM `ordersbuy` WHERE status = 1");
    $th_array = array();
    while ($row = $th_close->fetch_assoc()) {
        $th_array[] = $row;
    $closeord = time(); 
$res = $GLOBALS['mysqli']->query("INSERT INTO `trade_history`(`ID_prod`, `ID_poc`, `Val`, `Prod`, `Type`, `Price`, `Amount`, `Total`, `TimeCreateOrder`, `TimeCloseOrder`) VALUES (300,299,'".$row['Val']."','".$row['Prod']."','".$row['Type']."','".$row['price']."','".$row['amount']."','".$row['total']."','".$row['ordtime']."',$closeord)");
    }
```

Если в таблице ordersbuy 1 запись со статусом=1, то значение в trade_history вставляется, если больше записей, то уже нет.

Comment: *при этом вставить в 1 дополнительные значения, которых нет во 2ой таблице* И откуда же их взять - с потолка, что ли? Сервер не умеет работать с данными, которых у него нет...

Comment: Уточните вопрос. Какими средствами надо все это проделать? Сейчас это все можно сделать руками составив соответствующие запросы =)

Comment: @Skywave привел пример кода как пытался сделать, может так яснее будет